Configuring Alembic with Custom Settings
I'm attempting to configure Alembic for managing database migrations in my Python project. I've written a script to set up Alembic, but it seems that Alembic is not accepting the configuration parameters I provided. Instead, it creates a default alembic.ini file with default settings.
Here's my current script:
def setup_alembic(database_uri):
    try:
        # Configure Alembic
        alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
        alembic_cfg.set_main_option('script_location', 'lol')  # Update with your actual script location
        alembic_cfg.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', database_uri)

        # Initialize Alembic
        command.init(config=alembic_cfg, directory='alembic')

        # Generate and apply the initial migration
        command.revision(alembic_cfg, autogenerate=True, message='Initial migration')
        command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, 'head')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred during Alembic setup: {e}")

        # Define a cleanup function if needed (optional)
        # Call cleanup if necessary (uncomment if needed)
        cleanup()

The problem is that Alembic is not accepting the configuration parameters I provided. Instead, it creates a default alembic.ini file with default settings.
I expect Alembic to use the provided configuration parameters (script_location and sqlalchemy.url) instead of creating a default alembic.ini file.
I've also noticed that the script creates an alembic directory even if it already exists, which results in an error.
Can anyone guide me on how to correctly configure Alembic with custom settings using Python? What am I doing wrong in my script?
